# Smoother cones and better 3D arrows in Graphics

Tags: graphics

I have this code:

```
  openCone[{{x1_, y1_, z1_}, {x2_, y2_, z2_}}, r_] := {CapForm[None], 
      Tube[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}, {r, 0}]}
    Manipulate[
     Lcone = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Dashed, Black]], 
        LightGray, openCone[{{0, 0, 5}, {0, 0, 0}}, 4]}, Boxed -> False, 
       ViewPoint -> {5, 5, 2}];
     Lvec = Graphics3D[{Black, Arrowheads[0.05], 
        Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[4^2 - \[Rho]L^2], \[Rho]L, 5}}, 
          0.05]]}];
     Scone = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Dashed, Black]], Gray, 
        openCone[{{0, 0, 7}, {0, 0, 0}}, 3]}, Boxed -> False];
     Svec = Graphics3D[{Black, Arrowheads[0.05], 
        Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[3^2 - \[Rho]S^2], \[Rho]S, 7}}, 
          0.05]]}];
     Jvec = Graphics3D[{Black, Arrowheads[0.1], 
        Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, Sqrt[5^2 + 7^2]}}, 0.05]]}];
     Show[Lcone, Lvec, Scone, Svec, Jvec], {\[Rho]L, 1.12}, {\[Rho]S, 
      2.96}]
```

That produces this plot:
[image]

I would like to know whether it's possible:

- to make the cone smoother? You can see the triangulation
- How do I properly make the arrowhead match with the top of the arrow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can have custom arrowhead placements with the following specs:

[image]

The tubes can be rendered at higher fidelity with `Method -> {"TubePoints" -> pts}`.

```
openCone[{{x1_, y1_, z1_}, {x2_, y2_, z2_}}, r_] := {CapForm[None], 
  Tube[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}, {r, 0}]}

arrowHead[size_] := Arrowheads[{{size, 0.93, 
  {Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, .25]}], 0}}}]

Manipulate[
 Lcone = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Dashed, Black]], 
    LightGray, openCone[{{0, 0, 5}, {0, 0, 0}}, 4]}, Boxed -> False, 
   ViewPoint -> {5, 5, 2}];
 Lvec = Graphics3D[{Black, Arrowheads[0.05], 
    Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[4^2 - \[Rho]L^2], \[Rho]L, 5}}, 
      0.05]]}];
 Scone = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Dashed, Black]], Gray, 
    openCone[{{0, 0, 7}, {0, 0, 0}}, 3]}, Boxed -> False];
 Svec = Graphics3D[{Black, Arrowheads[0.05], 
    Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[3^2 - \[Rho]S^2], \[Rho]S, 7}}, 
      0.05]]}];
 Jvec = Graphics3D[{Black, Arrowheads[0.1], 
    Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, Sqrt[5^2 + 7^2]}}, 0.05]]}];
 Show[Lcone, Lvec, Scone, Svec, Jvec, Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 400}], {\[Rho]L, 1.12}, {\[Rho]S, 
  2.96}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, could you forward a documentation update request? "TubePoints" is not mentioned for Graphics3D Method.

Comment: In my prerelease of 12 it's mentioned in the `Graphics3D` Details & Options, which is how I found it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5UZ0.png

Comment: Sweet! Can't use v12 at the moment because FE goes crazy on my Win10.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I literally copied and pasted your code, but my arrows still come up like in picture. With part of the body sticking out of the head...

Comment: Hmm, does changing `arrowHeads` to `Arrowheads[{{size, 1, ...` fix things?

Comment: No it does nothing actually, does that mean something is not installed?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: Mathematica 11.3

Comment: @SuperCiocia same here... what OS?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro. You?

Comment: @SuperCiocia I’m on Mac. It could depend on the rendering engine. I’ll try to take a look tomorrow morning.

Comment: Just tried it on a Mac. Works fine. Any ideas on how to get it to produce nice arrowheads on Windows as well?